# On Part of the Proof of Stein's Identity

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

This comes from Exercise 37 on Tao's note. https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2015/10/03/275a-notes-1-integration-and-expectation/comment-page-1/#comment-681309

Let ${X}$ be a real random variable with the probability density function ${x \mapsto \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}}$ of the standard normal distribution. Establish the Stein identity

$\displaystyle {\bf E} X F(X) = {\bf E} F'(X)$

whenever ${F: {\bf R} \rightarrow {\bf R}}$ is a continuously differentiable function with ${F}$ and ${F'}$ both of polynomial growth (i.e., there exist constants ${C, A > 0}$ such that ${|F(t)|, |F'(t)| \leq C (1+|t|)^A}$ for all ${t \in {\bf R}})$.

**Question**: If we let $G: \mathbf{R} \rightarrow \mathbf{R}$ be such that $G(x) := xF(x)$, then $XF(X) = G(X)$ and so ${\bf E} X F(X) = {\bf E} G(X)$. But in order to proceeds to  $\displaystyle \mathop{\bf E} G(X) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{\bf R} G(x) e^{-x^2/2}\ dx$, one needs to ensure that ${G(X)}$ is absolutely integrable (or equivalently, that $\int_{\bf R} |G(x)| e^{-x^2/2}\ dx < \infty$. I'm not sure how to establish this condition given only that $|G(x)| e^{-x^2/2} = |xF(x)| e^{-x^2/2} \rightarrow 0$ as $x \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: If $F$ has polynomial growth then $x \mapsto x F(x)$ also has polynomial growth, which is much stronger and enough to get that your integral is finite (the growth is small with respect to the decay given by the exponential).

Comment: @Gâteau-Gallois: This makes intuitive sense enough. Can you give a more detailed and formal proof of the fact? (the note up till this point hasn’t developed other tools for deciding integrability).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment: with $C, A > 0$ given by the polynomial growth, for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $xF(x) \le xC(1+|x|)^A \le C' (1+|x|)^{A+1}$ for some constant $C' > 0$.
Hence \begin{align} \int_{\mathbb{R}} G(x) e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx &\le C' \int_{\mathbb{R}} (1+|x|)^{A+1} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx \\ &
\le C' \int_{-M}^M  (1+|x|)^{A+1}  dx + 2C' \int_M^\infty  (1+|x|)^{A+1}  e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} dx \end{align}
I have used parity to gather the $(-\infty, -M)$ case with the $(M, \infty)$ one.

For any fixed $M$, the first part on the rhs will be finite. But you can choose $M$ large enough so that $e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} \le \frac{1}{(1+|x|)^{A+3}}$ for all $x \ge M$ (since $x \mapsto (1+|x|)^{A+3} e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}$ decays continuously towards $0$). The second term on the rhs is then smaller than $\int_M^\infty (1+|x|)^{-2} dx \le \int_M^\infty x^{-2} dx$ which is integrable (by direct computation or comparison with the usual case).

Comment: Thank you. May I ask why can we conclude that $xC(1 + |x|)^A \leq C'(1 + |x|)^{A+1}$ for some positive $C'$?

Comment: $x\leq 1+|x|$ and pick $C’=C$